Wrong numbers retrieved in pytesseract
I'm trying to retrieve data from an online image with pytesseract, however the result is pretty bad and I was wondering if there was a way to improve it.

Here is my code:
import io
import requests
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
response = requests.get("https://port.jpx.co.jp/jpx/chart/chart21.exe?template=ini/DayIndexCSV&basequote=151_2024&begin=2024/4/2&end=2024/04/02&mode=D")
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
img.show()

#Updated black and white version
img.save('1.png')
image = cv2.imread('1.png',0)
_, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(image, 105, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(image, 106, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
final_thresh = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh1, thresh2)
im = Image.fromarray(final_thresh)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
print(text)
im.show()

As you can see the output is really different, from the real text.
It looks like a lot of numbers are being changed to "8", it can be 2,4,5 or 6.
also sometimes it gives "." for separator and sometimes ",".
Even if I select only a focus part, the answer is not better:
w, h= img.size
img2=img.crop((240, 185, w-220, h-220))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img2)
print(text)

The real value of the cropped image is "2,714.45" while this code returns "eT AS"
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img2, config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
print(text)

and this code returns only "1".
I don't understand really well how it works, I also tried to change the color according to what Use pytesseract OCR to recognize text from an image says, but it doesn't work either.
If someone have an idea on how I could make this work, that would be highly appreciated,
Thanks
Updated code:
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import requests
import io

response = requests.get("https://port.jpx.co.jp/jpx/chart/chart21.exe?template=ini/DayIndexCSV&basequote=151_2024&begin=2024/4/02&end=2024/04/02&mode=D")
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
grayscale_image = img.convert("L")
original_width, original_height = grayscale_image.size
factor = 300/72 # enlarge from default 72 to 300 dpi
new_width = int(original_width * factor)
new_height = int(original_height * factor)
enlarged_image = grayscale_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
threshold = 175 # found by trial/error (removes disturbing grid lines)
bw_image = enlarged_image.point(lambda x: 0 if x < threshold else 255, '1') # mode='1' -> b/w 

w, h= bw_image.size
bw_image=bw_image.crop((500, 0, w-300, h-480))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(bw_image)
print(text)
bw_image.show()

Output:
2U2d Ud Ue
2714.45
271445
2024/04/02


your entire post contains no usage or mention of OpenCV. I have removed the tag. you should only add related tags. a tag is a promise of content. do not call upon people on a tag without delivering related content.

You write "As you can see the output is really different, from the real text.", but do not provide any content suitable to see. The link given in the question throws an error "Invalid parameter".

@Claudio that looks perfect to me, Thanks a lot ! I'll accept it as soon  as I test it.
